# Uploading (XLSX) Files to Local Directory (Electron app)

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

We're building a local Electron App as a school project. I've already built and designed the app using HTML/CSS/JS, but now I'm tasked with implementing an upload feature. I've found different ways of uploading files, but none of them send the files to a local folder..

Could anyone help a brother out by showing/linking a way of uploading (multiple XLSX) files to a local folder?

(It would have to be a specific folder in the app's directory, as the other project members have to gain access to the files from there)

**Edit: Extra information about the app:** it's an "Excel based homework controller" where the teacher **uploads xlsx files** and the app controlls them (controlling part is not an issue).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show your best approach. If you manage to upload it, then where it's sent? And what is `local folder`?

Comment: @Justinas Unforunately I don't even have an exact approach as of now. Everything even remotely close has failed and gotten scrapped.. One which I really liked but didn't get to work: [link](https://www.codingnepalweb.com/file-upload-with-progress-bar-html-javascript/)

By Local Folder I mean a folder in the directory of the app itself, contrary to a cloud/database of sorts - the other members are going to pull the files from said folder to be worked (using Py, I think - I'm not too involved in that).

Comment: Calling it "uploading" isn't exactly right - it's more of sending/copying selected files to said folder.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.